# Does my server upload transfer data to realtime database counting in price?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, price, firebase-console

Does my server upload transfer data to realtime database counting in price? The SPARK price describes GB downloaded. I do not understand the standard.  Thanks!

[image: SPARK price]

[image: Firebase database bandwidth value]

Comment: In the spanish version, instead of GB downloaded, it says  _GB transferidos_ (GB transferred), so I understand that it's counting uploaded/downloaded data...

Comment: Thanks  for comment!

Comment: @anfuca thanks for the comment about the Spanish version. That seems like a mistranslation, so I've made a note to get it fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pricing for the Firebase Database and Firebase Storage are indicated only for downloaded data. Uploads are free.

Comment: Thank for reply! I have another question. Does the bandwidth value in console only include downloaded data? Like the above picture I've edited.

Comment: If you hover over the tiny question mark, it says "Bytes sent by the Realtime Database" (in English). So that indeed is only bytes downloaded, not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Uploads are not free. 
Every upload has an overhead of a few bytes. Tested uploading at different frequencies, it doesn't matter how much you upload, but how often.
If you update the timestamp of a field for example every 5 seconds you get approximately 200KB/hour download usage.
if you do it every 5 minutes it was around 2KB.

EDIT: When I tested I was sure to have the console closed. So that was not the cause.